# How to implement a "mailbox" service through mqtt?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I'm a newby to all things mqtt and as a first exercise I wanted to create a “mailbox” service through a persistent mqtt session. The incentive is a low power ESP8266 device that sleeps most of the time and periodically wakes up and checks if there are any pending commands for it.

I tried implementing this through a sender and receiver on my Linux host with python and paho mqtt. Mosquitto is running in the background as the broker.

First here is the "mbox" sender, which sends another message every time Enter is pressed.

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt 

broker_address='127.0.0.1'
client = mqtt.Client('MBoxClient') 
client.connect(broker_address)

counter = 1
while True:
  print('Press Enter to send msg #'+str(counter)+': ', end='')
  if input().startswith('q'):
    break
  client.publish("mbox/mail","Hello "+str(counter), qos=1)
  counter += 1
client.disconnect()
print('done!')
```

And here is my mbox receiver:

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
  print("message:", message.topic + ': ' + str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))

print('I\'m listening for mbox messages!')
broker_address="127.0.0.1"
client_name='mbox'
is_first=True
while 1:
  client = mqtt.Client(client_name, clean_session=is_first)
  is_first=False
  print("polling")
  client.on_message=on_message 
  client.connect(broker_address) 
  client.subscribe('mbox/#',qos=1)
  client.loop_start()
  time.sleep(0.1) # How long should this time be?
  client.loop_stop()
#  client.loop(0.1) # why doesn't this do the same action as the previous three lines?
  client.disconnect()
  time.sleep(5)
```

Even though this works, I feel that my solution is very hackish. `client.loop_start()` and `client.loop_stop()` creates another thread. But when I tried doing `client.loop(0.1)` instead it didn't work.

So my questions are:

- Is there a direct way of polling for a message, instead of the indirect method of using `loop_start();…;loop_stop()`?
- If using `loop_start();time.sleep(t);loop_end()` is idiomatic, how do I know how long time to sleep for?
- Why doesn’t the receiver work when I do `loop(0.1); instead of` loop_start(); sleep(0.1); loop_stop()`? What is the difference?
- Is the receiver guaranteed to receive all the messages?
- Is there a better way to implementing this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions answered in order.

- No, polling totally defeats the point of a pub/sub protocol like MQTT
- You should really be calling `client.loop()` in a loop, it defaults to only handling 1 packet in the timeout period supplied. QOS 1 needs multiple packets to complete delivery.
- calling `client.loop(0.1)` is going to block for 0.1 seconds waiting for an incoming message, then return. if a message arrives after that 0.1 seconds it's going to sit in the OS TCP/IP stack until you call `client.loop()` again. If you are not calling it on a regular interval then the broker is going to boot the client because the KeepAlive test will fail. The client loop also handles sending all the subscribe messages.
- Assuming the messages are published at QOS > 0 and you have subscribed at QOS > 0 and the client id is kept the same and clean session is false the broker should deliver and messages published while the subscriber is offline
- As previously mentioned you need to call `client.loop()` multiple times per message, as it is you are only calling it once per wake up period. Starting the background thread will handle all the required messages for the length of time you let it run for.

Comment: Thanks! Based on your comment I made a `while 1` loop around `client.loop()` and I check the time before and after the call. If the delta time is greater than `timeout-epsilon`, I break out of the loop. This seems to work fine. It would have been easier if `client.loop()` would have returned an indication on whether it timed out...